# Wrongly executing both "if" and "else" in While loop in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I’m just really learning Java, going through tutorials in book "Java how to Program" by Deitel and Deitel, so please forgive any basic mistakes I’m making. I understand my methodology might not be the best but I hope to improve this.

My problem is I believe I have constructed my program wrongly. Both the IF and ELSE options are being outputted when I execute the program.

If anyone could tell me why both options are executing it would be very much appreciated

Deepend

```
package controlStatments;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Review_4_20 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declare Variables
        double employeeOneRate;
        double employeeOneHours;
        double employeeTwoRate;
        double employeeTwoHours;
        double employeeThreeRate;
        double employeeThreeHours;
        int calculator;
        double employeeOneTotalPay;
        double employeeOneNormalPay;
        double employeeOneTotalPayOverTime;
        double overTimeRate;

        //Initiate Variables
        employeeOneRate = 0;
        employeeOneHours = 0;
        employeeTwoRate = 0;
        employeeTwoHours = 0;
        employeeThreeRate = 0;
        employeeThreeHours = 0;
        calculator = 0;
        employeeOneTotalPay = 0;
        employeeOneTotalPayOverTime = 0;
        overTimeRate = 1.5; 
        employeeOneNormalPay = 0;

        //Create While Loop
        while (calculator != -1)
        {   
            //Prompt user to input details
            System.out.print("\n\nPlease input the first employees rate");
            employeeOneRate =input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Please input the first employees Hours");
            employeeOneHours =input.nextDouble();

            if (employeeOneHours <= 40)
            {
                employeeOneTotalPay = employeeOneHours * employeeOneRate;
                System.out.printf("\nNormal time pay is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPay);
            }
            else 
                employeeOneNormalPay = employeeOneRate * 40;
            employeeOneTotalPayOverTime = (employeeOneHours - 40) * (employeeOneRate * overTimeRate) + employeeOneNormalPay;                            
            System.out.printf("\n\nTotal Pay including Overtime is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPayOverTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. Java allows initialize variables inline; i.e. instead of declaring and then initializing you could simply declare AND initialize in one line: double overTimeRate = 1.5; This would make your example much readable.

Comment: Thanks Arturs, that will help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (employeeOneHours <= 40)
        {
            employeeOneTotalPay = employeeOneHours * employeeOneRate;
            System.out.printf("\nNormal time pay is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPay);
        }
        else 
            employeeOneNormalPay = employeeOneRate * 40;
        employeeOneTotalPayOverTime = (employeeOneHours - 40) * (employeeOneRate * overTimeRate) + employeeOneNormalPay;                            
        System.out.printf("\n\nTotal Pay including Overtime is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPayOverTime);
```

With:

```
if (employeeOneHours <= 40)
        {
            employeeOneTotalPay = employeeOneHours * employeeOneRate;
            System.out.printf("\nNormal time pay is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPay);
        }
        else 
       {
            employeeOneNormalPay = employeeOneRate * 40;
        employeeOneTotalPayOverTime = (employeeOneHours - 40) * (employeeOneRate * overTimeRate) + employeeOneNormalPay;                            
        System.out.printf("\n\nTotal Pay including Overtime is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPayOverTime);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the bracket in your else statement.

I supose it should be like this :

```
    if (employeeOneHours <= 40)
    {
        employeeOneTotalPay = employeeOneHours * employeeOneRate;
        System.out.printf("\nNormal time pay is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPay);
    }
    else {
        employeeOneNormalPay = employeeOneRate * 40;
        employeeOneTotalPayOverTime = (employeeOneHours - 40) * 
                (employeeOneRate * overTimeRate) + employeeOneNormalPay;                                
        System.out.printf("\n\nTotal Pay including Overtime is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPayOverTime);
    }
```

If you don't set brackets only the first line is include in the IF/ELSE statement.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies, wont forget this for next time

Comment: @deepend It's not a bad habit to always use braces even when they are optional.  Sometimes we resist because it looks more "Elegant" without them when there is just one statement but I've never heard of anyone regretting using brackets when they were optional--yet everyone has at least one case where they wish they'd just used them.

Answer (score 1):

Bracketed statements, such as `if`, `else if`, `else`, and the loops only execute the line *immediately* following it if there is no bracket afterwards.

So, your statement:

```
if (employeeOneHours <= 40)
{
    employeeOneTotalPay = employeeOneHours * employeeOneRate;
    System.out.printf("\nNormal time pay is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPay);
}
else 
    employeeOneNormalPay = employeeOneRate * 40;
    employeeOneTotalPayOverTime = (employeeOneHours - 40) * (employeeOneRate * overTimeRate) + employeeOneNormalPay;                            
    System.out.printf("\n\nTotal Pay including Overtime is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPayOverTime);
```

*always* multiplies `employeeOneNormalPay`.

Change it to:

```
if (employeeOneHours <= 40) {
    employeeOneTotalPay = employeeOneHours * employeeOneRate;
    System.out.printf("\nNormal time pay is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPay);
} else {
    employeeOneNormalPay = employeeOneRate * 40;
    employeeOneTotalPayOverTime = (employeeOneHours - 40) * (employeeOneRate * overTimeRate) + employeeOneNormalPay;                            
    System.out.printf("\n\nTotal Pay including Overtime is: %.2f", employeeOneTotalPayOverTime);
}
```